# In Spring Data is it possible to delete entities using an entity's unique attribute?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Is it possible to delete entities using an entity's unique attribute?

In Spring Data 1.4.3.RELEASE, adding methods to find by unique attributes is very easy but, I haven't found a way to do it with delete.
In the following code, Spring automagically handles the `findByAddress`, **is there something similar for delete?**

Something like  `void deleteByAddress(String hwAddress);`, I have added it to `TerminalRepository` but it doesn't work.

```
public Terminal {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 private long id;
 @Column(unique=true)
 private String hwAddress;
 ...
}
```

```
public interface TerminalRepository extends
    CrudRepository<Terminal, Long> {

Terminal findByAddress(String hwAddress);

}
```

Of course it is possible to find the entity by `address` and then use the `delete(Terminal)` method passing the found entity as parameter. But this wouldn't be good in terms of performance as it will be making one unnecessary call to the database database, i.e., one avoidable call to find the object and another one to delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built-in for that. You'd have to use the custom method support to roll your own:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: Thanks.
It would be nice to have built-in support fro delete. Any clue of why there is not such support?

Comment: I don't know. Oliver Gierke is on here (StackOverflow) so if he sees this he might be able to answer. One thought though is that you might be able simply to create a dummy entity with only the ID set, and then pass that to the delete method. I'll bet it just calls delete using that ID. (You could turn on Hibernate show SQL to verify.) If I am right then it is just a single delete call.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. But, when I annotated method in repository interface with `@Modifying` , it started working. But, I don't know how it started working. Can anybody explain?

Comment: In Spring data, we just define the methods in the interface and this interface extends one of the standard Spring data repository interfaces. In this interface, try annotating your method by @Modifying. I don't know why, but after putting this annotation, it stops throwing exception and starts working.

Comment: Not working. I'll have to specifically write a query for delete. Putting `@Modifying` on a `deleteBy` method doesn't work.